# cexprtk with multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using the [cexprtk](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/cexprtk) wrapper in python to evaluate arithmetic expressions as it offers very fast evaluation compared to the standard `eval()`. For a large list of expressions the initial overhead is cumbersome as it has to compile all the terms which can take a long time.

However it offers a very nice feature whereby you only need to compile once and can then re-evaluate the expressions using different values for the variables later on; which I want to do.

I was wondering if it was possible to apply Python `multiprocessing` to this compilation process? I would break apart the large list of arithmetic expressions into sub-lists and feed them separately into functions which apply the cexprtk compilation to the different lists. These can then be run in parallel.

I attempted to do this, but the output is `nan` whatever I try. Here is a very simple example showing a working cexprtk code without multiprocessing:

```
import cexprtk

st = cexprtk.Symbol_Table({"W":1, "X":3, "Y":1, "Z":2}, add_constants= True) 

L = ['W+X+Y+Z','Y^2*W+Z']        

A = [cexprtk.Expression(x, st) for x in L]

print(A)[0]() ## This gives 3 which is correct 
print(A)[1]() ## This gives 7 which is correct
```

Now here is the attempt at using multiprocessing with two lists and two queues:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

import cexprtk

st = cexprtk.Symbol_Table({"W":1, "X":3, "Y":1, "Z":2}, add_constants= True) 

## Define two lists
L = ['W+X+Y+Z','Y^2*W+Z']     
L2 = ['W^5+Z-Y','Y^7+20-X']

## Define functions and put into queue (que)
def myfunc1(que):
    lst1 = [cexprtk.Expression(x, st) for x in L]  
    que.put(lst1)   

def myfunc2(que):
    lst2 = [cexprtk.Expression(x, st) for x in L2]  
    que.put(lst2)   

queue1 = Queue()    
queue2 = Queue()    
p1 = Process(target= myfunc1, args= (queue1,))    
p2 = Process(target= myfunc2, args= (queue2,)) 

p1.start()
p2.start()
ans = queue1.get()
ans2 = queue2.get()
print(ans1[0]()) # Gives nan
print(ans2[0]()) # Gives nan
```

I feel as though this falls in the category of "embarrassingly parallel problems" as the lists are completely separate and no communication is needed between the processes. I have used this exact method of multiprocessing before with great success; but in this instance it is not giving an answer; and as there are no error messages, I have not got any error feedback to work with.

If you use `eval()` instead it works without issue; so I assume it is the `cexprtk` wrapper. Is there a way to achieve what I am after? Or is the Python -> C++ -> Python too much for multiprocessing?

Comment: Do you have to return class objects? Could you take this one step further in your subprocesses and just return the list of values?

Comment: @Hannu I would like to compile all the expressions once and then reuse them without the need for compiling each time. In the example I gave I could reassign W,X,Y,Z and re-evaluate the list expressions without compilation again. From the multiprocessed code it does currently return the class object e.g. print(ans1[0]) =  <cexprtk.Expression object at 0x7f7025211878> but when I try to evaluate it, print(ans1[0]()) it gives nan. The first example without multiprocessing also returns the object, but I can extract the value out of it

Comment: I fear this will not work as you try do do it.  I did some experimenting, and if you add to myfunc1 `foo = copy.deepcopy(lst1[0])` and `print foo()`, you will get another nan. It appears not to be a multiprocessing issue as such, but as soon as you create a copy of cexprtk.Expression object, it loses access to its data and stops working.

Comment: The only solution as I see it is to extract all relevant information from those objects in your subprocess and return them instead of the object. If this invalidates your whole idea, then I fear this cannot be parallelised like this.

Comment: @Hannu Interesting, thank you for your comments and help. Ideally I would like to compile just once and then re-evaluate, as in theory I will need to re-evaluate these expressions thousands of times with different variables. Would it be possible to pickle the objects and store them to re-use? So no multi-processing involved but being able to store the compiled objects to re-use?

Comment: I do not think that would be possible. I actually tried that, but cexprtk.Expression cannot be pickled by anything.  Maybe you could create a client/server model of some kind, where the current subprocesses are always running and you communicate with them somehow. As long as they do not shut down, they can access their own data. If you can reduce the communication layer to data that contains something else than Expression objects, then it would work. If this voids the whole idea and you need to transmit that object, then I am out of options, as you cannot make a copy of it.